# not sure how to remove underline from image in css

Tags: css, image, underline

The site I am making has an image next to some text in a hyperlink.

The image is underlined and so is the text.  I would like the image to not be underlined.

```css
a {
   -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
   border-bottom: dotted 1px;
   color: #0066cc;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:hover {
   border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
   color: #0066cc !important;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 img {
   outline: none !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
   border-bottom: none;
   outline-width: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<a href="domain.com"><img src="pic.gif">check this out></a>
```

It did not work.

The underline goes away if you hover over the image, but I want it to not be there ever.

Comment: Then why are you writing `border-bottom: dotted 1px;`?

Comment: I want it to be underlined when you are not hovering on it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to remove line only under image, please use following code :-**

CSS :-

```
a 
{
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;

    color: #0066cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a span{
border-bottom: dotted 1px;
}
a span:hover {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    color: #0066cc !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML :-

```
<a href="domain.com"><img src="pic.gif"><span>check this out></span></a>
```

**If you want to remove line from whole image and text, please use following code :-**

CSS :-

```
a 
    {
        -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;

        color: #0066cc;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
a span{
border-bottom: dotted 0px;
}
a span:hover {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    color: #0066cc !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML :-

```
<a href="domain.com"><img src="pic.gif"><span>check this out></span></a>
```

Comment: this hides the underline at all times for text, too.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text into the `<span></span>`, remove underline from link and set underline only for that span. It should work.